# how to add a header when you write a csv file with python

Tags: python, selenium, csv, header

I retrieve a html tag of several pages and I want to save them in a csv file whose headers are:
a , b ,c d, requete , url_resultat , url rang
but I can not get what you can help me.

```py
with open('requetetest123.csv', 'w',newline='') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames = ["a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "requete" , "url_resultat" , "url_rang"], delimiter = ';')
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in csvReader:
            requete=row[0]
            h=get_result_line(send_requete(browser,requete))
            row_write= (requete,h)
            writer.writerow(row_write)
    csvFile.close()
```

Comment: small note: you don't need `csvFile.close()`, the `with` takes care of this for you :)

Comment: What is wrong with your current output? 'but I can not get what you can help me' is not an accurate enough description of the problem you encounter. Please give us your current vs expected output.

Comment: `writer.writeheader()` should be doing this for you already....

Comment: wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'keys'   this is the error

Comment: Please include the **complete** error traceback in your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add header in `csv` try the following code.

```
import csv
fieldnames = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "requete", "url_resultat", "url_rang"]
with open('requetetest123.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(h for h in fieldnames)
```